# IOS - Test the fb login button

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, xctest

following the tutorial on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios I created a fb login and log out button. Now I want to test the app using the user interface with Xcode XCTest. My question now is how do I test that I can press the login button and assert that I can see the Log out button.

Comment: You might want to consider providing some background on your testing platform. Are you testing via UI Test or Unit Test? It can make a difference.

Comment: I am doing a UI test @BillBurgess

Comment: Unfortunately your options are extremely limited when using XCTest for UI testing. There are no means to inject code or mock data as these types of tests run differently than Unit Tests. All you can do is program the various clicks and check if things exist or not. It might work, but would be hitting live Facebook calls and logins, and that isn't something you'd ideally want for testing.